# How to join two table on two similar keys?

Tags: sql

I have two data tables like

T1:

```
key1 value
ac ..
abc ..
```

T2:

```
key2 value2
ab ..
dd ..
```

Now, I want to join T1 and T2 on key1 and key1 with the condition that key2 is
 substring of key1. How to write efficient SQL query to do this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really write *efficient* SQL for this.  You can express it as:

```
select t.*, t2.*
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.key1 like concat('%', t2.key2, '%');
```

(Note:  most databases support a string concatenation operator such as `||` or `+`.)

This will not be efficient -- which would normally refer to the use of indexes.  That is not really possible with substring operations.

If performance is really important, I would suggest that you ask another question with sample data and a description of the results you need.